# Load mobile CSS if user is on Android

Tags: javascript, android, css, mobile, viewport

My .htaccess file is writing a "smart" cookie. If my page reads this cookie it will write a div. Then my mobile CSS file loads only if the user's on an iPhone or iPod.

My question is, how can I edit this code (below) to load the mobile CSS file if the user's on an Android?

Here's my [page](http://bit.ly/ilPPqN) and code:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=yes" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mobile.css" media="only screen and (max-width: 640px)" /> 
<script type="text/javascript">
if (window.screen.width > 640){document.write('<meta name="viewport" content="width=980, user-scalable=yes" />')}
if((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))){document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mobile.css" media="only screen and (max-width: 640px)" />')}
</script>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should just be able to add

`|| (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i))`

to the second `if statement`, so

```
if( (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || 
    (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)) || 
    (navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i)) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you goes :)

http://davidwalsh.name/detect-android

Answer (score 0):

This snippet will do it:

```
navigator.userAgent.match(/android/)
```