# div with font size independent from viewport / zoom

Tags: zooming, font-size, viewport

I'm building a bookmarklet that needs to have it's font sizes independent of the viewport or zoom level of the current page (when the javascript is injected).

What happens now (on tablets + phones mainly) is that the fonts are too small when the page fits the mobile viewport (or really small zoom levels on a PC browser).

Here's a screen grab:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/liO0C.png

Does anyone know a way to do this? Javascript or CSS solutions are great by me.

Thanks!

Sean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Check This -**

1. [Preserve HTML font-size when iPhone orientation changes from portrait to landscape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2710764/preserve-html-font-size-when-iphone-orientation-changes-from-portrait-to-landscap)
2. [Load mobile CSS if user is on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6459692/load-mobile-css-if-user-is-on-android)

**Even you can have Javasacript -**

```
<script>        

if ((navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) 
{

var t= '';       

document.write('<link href=http://..../.../your.css media=all rel=stylesheet type=text/css />');

}       

</script>
```

**Tutorial Site :**

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/redirect-mobile-devices/

http://www.gethifi.com/blog/three-ways-to-target-mobile-devices